# Golang: how to send html body email with image using base64 string as attachment content

Tags: go, smtp, base64

I have the following msg which i receive in my golang handler:

```
{"fromDisplayName":"ForgottenPassword","to":["example@gmail.com"],"cc":[],"bcc":[],"subject":"ForgottenPassword","body":" \t<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> <html> \t<head> \t\t<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html charset=UTF-8\" /> \t\t<title>Forgot Password Email</title> \t</head> \t<body style=\"width:100%; border:0; padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center; background-color:#f3f3f3; font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size:1em\">\t\t \t\t<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%; max-width: 680px; margin: auto; margin-top: 30px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);\"> \t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t<td>\t\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\t\t<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%;\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"background-color:#ffffff; height:4em; padding:1.5em;\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%;\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: left;\"></td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"width: 100%; height: 1px; background-color: #ccc;\"></td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t</table> \t\t\t\t\t<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%;\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t<tbody> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"width:100%; padding:30px; text-align: center; background-color:#ffffff\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px; text-align: center; font-size:2.5em; font-weight:lighter; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 28px; color: #434795;\">Hi user</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"text-align: center; font-size:1em; padding-top:0.8em; padding-bottom:2em; color:#999999\">You're already a user, so there is no need to sign up.</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"text-align: center; font-size:1em; padding-top:0.8em; padding-bottom:2em; color:#999999\">If you forgot your password, you can reset it .</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"text-align: center;\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a><img src=\"cid:278da187427a4bdcaceb76781f4a3753\" alt=\"forgot password\" width=\"100\" height=\"60\" border=\"0\"></a> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style = \"font-size:0.75em; padding-top:3.5em; padding-bottom:1.25em; text-align: center; color:#999999\">If you received this email by mistake, you can just delete it.</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" text-align=\"center\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f3f3f3\" width=\"100%\" style=\"max-width: 680px\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t <tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\" font-size: 0.75em; text-align: center; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:17px; padding-top: 20px;\"> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span style=\"color: #999999;\">We don't check this mailbox, so please don't reply to this message.</span><br> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"mobile-link--footer;\" style=\"color: #999999;\"></span><br><br> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr> \t\t\t\t\t\t</tbody> \t\t\t\t\t</table>\t\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\t</td>\t \t\t\t</tr> \t\t</table>\t\t \t</body> </html>","isHtmlBody":true,"attachments":[{"fileName":"click_button.png","content":"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","contentType":"image/png","contentDisposition":"inline","cid":"278da187427a4bdcaceb76781f4a3753"}]}
```

My purpose is to send the information in the msg as an email via google smtp.

im able so send the message but the image content in the message(base64 string) is not embeded in the email html body. when i send the same message using nodejs and nodemailer - the image is shown correctly.

how can i achive this?

this is an example of one of the approaches i tried and does not show the  image in the email body ("github.com/jordan-wright/email"):

```
func EmailServiceBusinessLogic(receivedMsg emailModels.ReceivedMsgModel) error{


    mail := email.NewEmail()

    for _,v := range receivedMsg.Attachments{
        if v.FileName == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty file name for attachment")
            continue
        }
        if v.Cid == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty cid for file name: ", v.FileName)
            continue
        }
        if v.ContentType == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty ContentType for file name: ", v.FileName)
            continue
        }
        if v.Content == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty Content for file name: ", v.FileName)
            continue
        }

        mail.Attach(strings.NewReader(v.Content)  , v.Cid, v.ContentType)
    }

    if receivedMsg.FromDisplayName == "" {
        fmt.Println("received empty FromDisplayName: aborting send")
        return errors.New("received empty FromDisplayName: aborting send")

    }
    fromWithoutWhiteSpaces := strings.Join(strings.Fields(receivedMsg.FromDisplayName), "")


    mail.From = fromWithoutWhiteSpaces+"@dont-reply.com"
    mail.To = receivedMsg.To
    mail.Bcc = receivedMsg.Bcc
    mail.Cc = receivedMsg.Cc
    mail.Subject = receivedMsg.Subject
    if receivedMsg.IsHtmlBody {
        mail.HTML = []byte(receivedMsg.Body)
    }else {
        mail.Text = []byte(receivedMsg.Body)
    }


    err := mail.Send(emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Host+":587", smtp.PlainAuth("", emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Username, emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Password, emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Host))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

EDIT:

### SOLVED

thanks to  @Steffen Ullrich comments Because in my json the image content already base64 encoded and the library will put another base64 layer on top of it, so I had to base64 decode it first like so:

```
func EmailServiceBusinessLogic(receivedMsg emailModels.ReceivedMsgModel) error {

    mail := email.NewEmail()

    for _, v := range receivedMsg.Attachments {
        if v.FileName == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty file name for attachment")
            continue
        }
        if v.Cid == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty cid for file name: ", v.FileName)
            continue
        }
        if v.ContentType == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty ContentType for file name: ", v.FileName)
            continue
        }
        if v.Content == "" {
            fmt.Println("received empty Content for file name: ", v.FileName)
            continue
        }

        // Base64 Standard Decoding <-this is the part that was missing!!
        sDec, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(v.Content)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error decoding Content: %s ", err.Error())
            continue
        }

        mail.Attach(strings.NewReader(string(sDec)), v.Cid, v.ContentType)
    }

    if receivedMsg.FromDisplayName == "" {
        fmt.Println("received empty FromDisplayName: aborting send")
        return errors.New("received empty FromDisplayName: aborting send")

    }
    fromWithoutWhiteSpaces := strings.Join(strings.Fields(receivedMsg.FromDisplayName), "")

    mail.From = fromWithoutWhiteSpaces + "@dont-reply.com"
    mail.To = receivedMsg.To
    mail.Bcc = receivedMsg.Bcc
    mail.Cc = receivedMsg.Cc
    mail.Subject = receivedMsg.Subject
    if receivedMsg.IsHtmlBody {
        mail.HTML = []byte(receivedMsg.Body)
    } else {
        mail.Text = []byte(receivedMsg.Body)
    }

    err := mail.Send(emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Host+":587", smtp.PlainAuth("", emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Username, emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Password, emailGlobals.SmtpConf.Body[0].Value.Host))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `v.ContentType` correct?

Comment: @Burak Serdar : content type is "image/png"...

Comment: The problem with all these packages is that they create a multipart/mixed mail. But you need a multipart/related so that the images and the HTML are considered to belong together. I have seen no way to change this behavior without changing the source, i.e. it is hard coded.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: i changed the code in the library("github.com/jordan-wright/email" in the Bytes() method) i use from: headers.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed;\r\n boundary="+w.Boundary()) to: headers.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/related;\r\n boundary="+w.Boundary()) -> but still with the change the resoult email html body does not show the image

Comment: @VitalyGo877: But does the attached image even load correctly? Because in your json it is already base64 encoded and the library will put another base64 layer on top of it, so you likely need to base64 decode it first.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: thanks! it worked :) going now to update the question with the answer. fyi: the change i did before in the library from "mixed" to "related" -> i revensed it back as it works without the need in that change..thank you so much!

Comment: @VitalyGo877: see also my updated answer

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: i marked it as the accepted answer and will try again to give it a vote up once my rep go over 15 (the minimum required by the site for a vote up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference an attached image from inside the HTML it must have a `Content-Id`, i.e. in the HTML it needs to look like this:

```
`<img src="cid:000001.png">
```

Looking at the source of `Attach` in `"github.com/jordan-wright/email` which I assume you use it shows that it is [using the given filename](https://github.com/jordan-wright/email/blob/master/email.go#L254) as `Content-Id`:

```
func (e *Email) Attach(r io.Reader, filename string, c string) (a *Attachment, err error) {
    ....
    at.Header.Set("Content-ID", fmt.Sprintf("<%s>", filename))
```

Thus, make sure that the `v.FileName` you use as name for your attachment is actually used as the `cid` in the HTML part.

---

After more information were added to the question:

> ... the only information i have regarding the attachments is: file name, content(string), content type(image/png) and contentDisposition atribute set to inline and cid

In this case you the `cid` and not file name.

---

With even more information added to the question:

> have the following msg which i receive in my golang handler:
>
> ```
> {"fromDisplayName":"Forg...
> ```

It looks like that your image is already base64 encoded, but the library you use does an additional base64 encoding, so you have to decode it first. Also the library explicitly uses a `Content-Type` of `multipart/mixed` but it needs to be `multipart/related` so that the images are associated with the HTML.

The following code works for me with the JSON from your question stored as `mail.json`. Note that I omitted error checking in several places in order to focus on the solution. And I don't directly send the mail but store it only as a string to store it as an EML file and check it. You likely need to change the [`Bytes` function](https://github.com/jordan-wright/email/blob/master/email.go#L369) to set `multipart/related` directly there:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jordan-wright/email"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "strings"
)

type Attachments struct {
    Filename string `json:"filename"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    ContentType string `json:"contentType"`
    ContentDisposition string `json:"contentDisposition"`
    Cid string `json:"cid"`
}

type Mail struct {
    To []string `json:"to"`
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
    Parts []Attachments `json:"attachments"`
}

func main() {
    f,_ := os.Open("mail.json")
    d := json.NewDecoder(f)
    m := &Mail{}
    d.Decode(&m)
    // fmt.Println(m)

    e := email.NewEmail()
    e.To = m.To
    e.Subject = m.Subject
    e.HTML = []byte(m.Body)
    for _,p := range m.Parts {
        s,_ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(p.Content))
        e.Attach(bytes.NewReader(s), p.Cid, p.ContentType)
    }
    s,_ := e.Bytes()
    mail := strings.Replace(string(s),": multipart/mixed;",": multipart/related;",1)
    fmt.Println(mail)
}
```

Comment: thank you, im going to try now( i updated the question with more relevant info ) - and will update. thanks a lot!

Comment: @VitalyGo877: use the cid then, see updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time! i tried with cid instead of the name and i tried to switch to another library ("github.com/domodwyer/mailyak") which exposes AttachInline method which i use as you suggested: mail.AttachInline(attachment.Cid, &b) where b is bytes.buffer of the string content of the file (var b bytes.Buffer and then b.WriteString(attachment.Content))...its still the same when the mail arrives the images are not embedded.. the only difference i can see between the golang and nodejs is that in node: im sending the content as buffer from base64 string - so i will try to fin

Comment: @VitalyGo877: I think you should need to do a minimal but complete example so that one can reproduce in full what you are actually doing. For now this is just guessing what you are really doing and how the final mail message looks like and where your errors are.

Comment: i edited the question and added the object i receive + the code i use..really any way to just get the image to show in golang is what im after..i dont really care what library and such...thank you